# Asterisk 13 Queue Overflow using joinempty=inuse fails

Tags: queue, overflow, asterisk

I have configured a queue filled by static or dynamic members (both tested) and joinempty=true. When all the members are busy, any other incoming call is placed into the queue instead of following dialplan next steps.
Any help would be great

Comment: Not clear what is problem. You have joinempty=true, it work like when joinempty is true. What is your problem?

Comment: Thabk you for the reply arheops. You are completelly rigth. It is wrong, The issue is using joinempty=inuse.

Answer (score 0):

Seams like you not understand what policy do.

```
; joinempty = yes

Asterisk 1.8:

; paused - a member is not considered available if he is paused
; penalty - a member is not considered available if his penalty is less than QUEUE_MAX_PENALTY
; inuse - a member is not considered available if he is currently on a call
; ringing - a member is not considered available if his phone is currently ringing
; unavailable - This applies mainly to Agent channels. If the agent is a member of the queue but has not logged in, then do not consider the member to be available
; invalid - Do not consider a member to be available if he has an "invalid" device state. This generally is caused by an error condition in the member's channel driver.
; unknown - Do not consider a member to be available if we are unable to determine the member's current device state.
; wrapup - A member is not considered available if he is currently in his wrapuptime after taking a call.
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. The problem is using joinempty = inuse